# Два массива для ArrayAdapter или два ArrayAdapter для ListView

Tags: android

Мне нужно заполнить `ListView` двумя массивами. Для обоих массивов своя разметка. Чтобы это сделать, мне нужно заполнить `ListView` сначала одним массивом, потом другим. Для этого мне нужно или "засунуть" и как-то обработать два массива для `ArrayAdapter` или установить по очереди два адаптера два `ListView`. Как это можно реализовать и что лучше?

Comment: Написать кастомный адаптер и передавать в конструкторе два массива - это будет лучше. PS:для вопросов по андроид ставьте основную метку android

Comment: @pavlofff, я попробовал такой вариант. Зайдите в соседнюю тему...

Comment: @pavlofff, она не совсем связная, но вот — http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462883/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-custombaseadapter