# Не работает CustomBaseAdapter

Tags: android

Я создал `CustomBaseAdapter` унаследовавшись от `BaseAdapter`:

```
public class CustomListAdapter_Words extends BaseAdapter {
    private static String TAG = "myApplication";
    private static String MSG = "Adapter: ";

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[][] names;

    public CustomListAdapter_Words(Activity context, String[][] names) {
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView_1;
        public TextView textView_2;
        public TextView textView_3;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "1");
        ViewHolder holder;
        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_words_form_1, null, true);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.textView_1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
            holder.textView_2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
            holder.textView_3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_3);

            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView_1.setText(names[position][0]);
        holder.textView_1.setText(names[position][1]);
        holder.textView_1.setText(names[position][2]);

        Log.i(TAG, MSG + names[position][0] + names[position][1] + " " + names[position][2]);

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Вызываю его так:

```
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_words, null);
    ((ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.table_words_listView_1)).setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter_Words(this, values));
```

Выполнение даже не начинается! В чем проблема? `ArrayAdapter` работал, но не давал нужный результат (не разрешал работу с двухмерным массивом).

Comment: С такими значениями переопределенных методов, как 0, null он и не будет работать. В частности вы указываете, что в адаптере НОЛЬ элементов, а отдаваемые по запросу айтемы - null (ничто). Надежды, что это могло бы работать никакой. Если уж вы собрались переопределять методы адаптера - позаботьтесь узнать о их назначении.

Comment: @pavlofff, да я и не хотел переопределять. Меня заставили :D. Эх... Пойду разбираться.

Comment: @pavlofff, раньше просто ничего не делал, а теперь еще и приложение падает... — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/463094/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0