# Ошибка при назначении адаптера

Tags: android

Во время выполнения этого метода происходит ошибка (`values` — это двумерный массив):

```
private View makeWords() {
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_words, null);
        ((ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.table_words_listView_1)).setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter_Words(this, values));

        return v;
    }
```

Ошибка во время назначения адаптера.

Вот вызов метода:

```
pages = new View[3];
pages[0] = makeWords();
```

Вот сам адаптер:

```
public class CustomListAdapter_Words extends BaseAdapter {
    private static String TAG = "myApplication";
    private static String MSG = "Adapter: ";

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[][] names;

    public CustomListAdapter_Words(Activity context, String[][] names) {
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView_1;
        public TextView textView_2;
        public TextView textView_3;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_words_form_1, null, true);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.textView_1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
            holder.textView_2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
            holder.textView_3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_3);

            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView_1.setText(names[position][0]);
        holder.textView_1.setText(names[position][1]);
        holder.textView_1.setText(names[position][2]);

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        String[][] item = new String[1][3];

        item[0][0] = names[position][0];
        item[0][0] = names[position][1];
        item[0][0] = names[position][2];

        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Но до него выполнение не доходит (смотрел по логу).

Вот .xml разметка для адаптера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="46"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_3"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="46"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Вот stacktrace ошибки:

```
11-01 21:55:37.539    4103-4103/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity.makeWords(MainActivity.java:187)
            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

Я подозреваю, что что-то накосячил в адаптере (`ArrayAdapter` стандартный работал), но где именно? Что я не так делаю?

---

Выяснилось что `ListView` равен `null`, но почему?

Вот метод:

```
private View makeWords() {
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_words, null);
    ListView myList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.table_words_listView_1);

    if (myList == null) Log.i(TAG, MSG + "NULL!!!");

    myList.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter_Words(this, values));

    return v;
}
```

Вот разметка `table_words`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/table_words_listView_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Почему `ListView` равен `null`?

Comment: Ищите NPE в 187 строке класса ```MainActivity```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос разметку R.layout.table_words

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что сам ListView не находит.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, хм... `ListView` действительно равен `null`, но почему?!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я дополнил вопрос. Давайте удалим ненужные комментарии.

Comment: Кстати, думаю, если тут `getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_words, null);` вы вместо null укажете любой (например корневой) элемент вашей активити и 3-им аргументом поставите true, то listView уже не будет null. Оно, конечно, вашей проблемы в корне не решит, но падать должно будет перестать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я уже переписываюсь под фрагменты (не нашел  нормального объяснения, часть не понял, так что работаю на уровне интуиции :)).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, черт! Вообще ничего не работает.

Comment: @bukashka101, IDE падает с фатальной ошибкой?.. =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нет... Такое у меня было только тогда, когда я пытался программу, написанную на Паскале, в .apk компилировать :)). Но потом вышло! Вроде с фрагментами разобрался, стандартный адаптер работает (пол часа искал пропущенный `return`, который крашил программу). Не понял, как идут вызовы фрагментов, но вызываются — значит нужно менять их. Сейчас пойду пробовать всовывать туда `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, вы назначаете адаптер списку до добавления разметки, его содержащей в разметку, уже загруженную в активити. Попробуйте сначала добавить список в разметку активити методом `addView(View)`, а потом уже устанавливать адаптер списку.

Comment: Что значит "до добавления разметки, его содержащей в разметку, уже загруженную в активити"? Я немного запутался... И я вообще эту разметку не устанавливаю, а передаю `View` в `ViewPagger`.

Comment: И можете поподробнее: как добавить список в разметку активити и зачем? Я эту разметку не ставлю разметкой активити, по скольку использую ее для `ViewPagger`.

Comment: Ну... Вы, похоже, что там очень сложное наворотили... ВьюПэджер лучше с фрагментами пользовать... Я часто делал ВьюПэджер  с фрагментами, содержащими списки с адаптерами и всё отлично работало. А вот как ВьюПэджер работает с вьюхами обычными я хз. И вот так назначать адаптер списку, коий потом в ВьюПэджер передаётся... Это звучит крайне странно.

Comment: То есть, идти учить `ViewPagger` для фрагметов?(

Comment: А так, думаю, должно вам помочь установление адаптера списку в переопределённом слушателе выбора страницы ViewPager... Но таки это да - лучше через фрагменты делать.

Comment: А фрагменты не будут каждый раз новую разметку создавать, при изменении страницы? В `ListView` будут загружаться тысячи строк из SQLite базы данных (чувствую, что я приду еще сюда с проблемой оптимизации, так как у меня и с сотней все тормозит), так что перезагрузка каждый раз будет лишней.

Comment: ViewPager загружает и сохраняет фрагменты. Засим, указав ему сохранять все загруженные фрагменты он не будет их пересоздавать при перелистывании оных.

Comment: Ура! Адаптер не крашит приложение и работает (но не правильно... попробую разобраться сам)!